# How do I store variable of user input into specific address using ARM assembly

Tags: arm

User inputs a value and is read into using scanf and it is scored into variable. I want to put that variable into a specific address that we have defined.
I tried using [var name] dcd [value] but it does not work.
This is my code

```
/* -- printf01.s */
.data
address dcd 0x2000000
/* First message */
.balign 4
ask_number: .asciz "Enter a number to store: "

.balign 4
ask_address: .asciz "Enter an addresss:"

/* Second message */
.balign 4
read_number: .asciz "Number from user input is %d\n"

.balign 4
read_address: .asciz "Number in address %d is %d\n"

/* Format pattern for scanf */
.balign 4
scan_pattern: .asciz "%d"

/* Where scanf will store the number read */
.balign 4
number: .word 0

.balign 4
return: .word 0

.text
.global main
main:
ldr r1, =return
str lr, [r1] @ save return address into return

ldr r0, =ask_number @ r0 <- &message1
bl printf @ call to printf

ldr r0, =scan_pattern @ r0 <- &scan_pattern
ldr r1, =number @ r1 <- &number_read
bl scanf @ call to scanf

ldr r0, =read_number
ldr r1, =number
ldr r1, [r1]
bl printf

ldr r0, =read_address @ r0 <- &message2
ldr r1, =number @ r1 <- &number_read
ldr r2, [r1] @ r1 <- *r1
bl printf @ call to printf

ldr lr, =return
ldr lr, [lr] @ load return address
bx lr

/* External */
.global printf
.global scanf
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it (assuming the value you want to store at `0x2000000` is in `r1`)

```
mov r0,0x2000000
str r1,[r0]
```